# Paperclip upload to S3 is failing silently...help!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have an application which uploads images to an S3 bucket using Paperclip. It's been working fine for months, but suddenly my files are not being uploaded to the S3 bucket. Unfortunately, I've been doing a refactoring in a number of unrelated areas, and it's possible that something I changed broke my upload.

I'm using paperclip 2.3.1.

That said, there are a number of confusing aspects to this and frankly I am at a loss. First, there are no errors in the log indicating that the upload failed. The paperclip attachment attributes are populated in the database. The application thinks the upload occurred successfully. But when I look in S3, the file is not there.

Second, I have an almost identical attachment on a different model, which uploads to the same S3 bucket successfully -- the code is almost identical, and there clearly cannot be a permissions issue.

I found references in several places that suggested removing the right_aws game and instead only having the aws_s3 gem...which I did...but to no avail. Moreover, I never saw the (5 for 4) error in my log regardless.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can further diagnose this? Are there any options in paperclip to increase the verbosity of logging?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similiar problem with paperclip 2.3.4. I can upload a lot of files, but with some files it just fails, with no err msg! If I make a copy of the file, it works. If I just rename it, it fails. It happens with S3 only(ok with :filesystem), and with only a few files. Drives my crazy!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well and the cause was that my :multipart => true key/value hadn't been nested correctly in the :html key of the form_for helper.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the app was using Paperclip 2.3.4 which introduced some S3 issues.

Upgrading to 2.3.5 solved the issue for me.

Comment: Just upgraded from Paperclip 2.3.3 to 2.3.5 and it still has the problem. :(

Comment: I finally did figure out my orginal problem (after many weeks of pounding my head against the wall). My model object has a callback which was not returning a true value. That was causing subsequent callbacks to not be called, which apparently is important for paperclip. I hope that helps.